# lightning modal window not opening

Tags: javascript, lightning

I must be doing something wrong. All of my debug lines output properly but It isn't opening up the popup modal window

```
<aura:attribute name="ShowCannotDeleteModel" type="Boolean" default="false" />
```

in js controller :

```
}else if (menuValue == component.get("v.DeleteLabel")){
            console.log("in delete");
            component.set("v.SelectedRecord", selectedRecordId);
            console.log("set record");
            var action = component.get("c.candelete");    
            console.log("action");
            action.setParams({
            contactid : selectedRecordId
            });
           action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var bcandelete = response.getReturnValue();
               if(bcandelete){
                   component.set("v.ShowDeleteModel", true);
                   console.log("can delete");
               }else {
            component.set("v.ShowCannotDeleteModel", true);
                   console.log("cannot delete");
               }   
        })
              console.log("before enqueue");
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
            console.log("after");

        }
```

back in component:

```
  <!-- Cannot Delete Modal -->      
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.ShowCannotDeleteModel}">
        <div class="demo-only" style="height: 640px;">
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close">

                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Modal Header</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <p>You do not own this contact</p>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick="{!c.CloseModel}">Ok</button>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
```

Comment: where according to you are you calling an action to open a modal?

Comment: I must misunderstand, the modal is in an auraif which means it is visible if it's true, therefore after i         $A.enqueueAction(action); and set v.ShowCannotDeleteModel to true, then it should open up the modal

Comment: Just a little sidenote, but instead of craftin your own modal - best use someone else's open source version:http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeModal
You'd invoke it using `component.find('modalAuraID').show()` or by firing an event, whichever is more convenient.
Finally, don't waste your time with `console.log` but put `debugger` in your code or event better - setup inline breakpoints using Chrome's tools. That will allow to inspect code live at run-time and avoid cluttering your code. Just press cmd+option+f and search for your function name and click on line number you want to pause on

Comment: or use lightning:overlayLibrary, and the modal the OP is using is the component markup provided by SLDS's documentation.

Comment: @Tim Willis, any reason why you do not leverage the lightning:overlayLibrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented similar type of modal popup myself using aura:if, this should work. It seems you are missing a semi colon at the end of the action.setCallback.

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
     var bcandelete = response.getReturnValue();
        if(bcandelete){
             component.set("v.ShowDeleteModel", true);
             console.log("can delete");
         } else {
             component.set("v.ShowCannotDeleteModel", true);
             console.log("cannot delete");
         }   
 });
```

Comment: Pukeee, semicolons are optional in JS. It can lead to semicolon confusion, but not in this case.